# asp.net web forms JQuery dropdownlists no postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, drop-down-menu

I am using JQuery to populate a set of three cascading dropdowns which have the autopostback to false. How in the code behind do I access the selected values of the dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DdlElement.SelectedItem.Value ?